# Kubernetes Ingress path based routing not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I installed [NGINX Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) in kubernetes cluster. When i am trying to access the micro service end via Ingress Controller its not working as expected

I have deployed two spring boot application

**Ingress  Rules**

- Path 1 -> /customer
- Path 2 -> /prac

When i am trying to access one of the service  ex. 
**http://test.practice.com/prac/practice/getprac** , it does not work

[image]

but when i try to access without Ingress path **http://test.practice.com/practice/getprac**, it works

[image]

I am not able to understand why with Ingress path its not working and same happens for other service

Micro service 1 (Port 9090)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: customer
  namespace: practice
  labels: 
    app: customer
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: customer
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: customer
    spec: 
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: testkuldeepsecret
      containers:
      - name: customer
        image: kuldeep99/customer:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          hostPort: 9090

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:                     
  name: customer-service
  namespace: practice
  labels: 
spec:                         
  ports: 
  - port: 9090 
    targetPort: 9090
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: customer
```

Micro service 2 (port 8000)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prac
  namespace: practice
  labels: 
    app: prac
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels: 
      app: prac
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: prac
    spec: 
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: testkuldeepsecret
      containers:
      - name: prac
        image: kuldeep99/practice:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          hostPort: 8000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:                     
  name: prac-service
  namespace: practice
  labels: 
spec:                         
  ports: 
  - port: 8000 
    targetPort: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: prac
```

Service (customer-service and prac-service)

```
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
customer-service   ClusterIP   10.97.203.19    <none>        9090/TCP   39m
ngtest             ClusterIP   10.98.74.149    <none>        80/TCP     21h
prac-service       ClusterIP   10.96.164.210   <none>        8000/TCP   15m
some-mysql         ClusterIP   None            <none>        3306/TCP   2d16h
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: practice-ingress
  namespace: practice
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec: 
  rules:
  - host: practice.example.com
    http: 
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: customer-service
          servicePort: 9090
        path: /customer
      - backend:
          serviceName: prac-service
          servicePort: 8000
        path: /prac
```

Answer (score 5):

You have installed this [nginx ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress)

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` annotation to work properly you need to install this [nginx ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx).

Alternative way to solve this issue is to configure contextPath to `/prac` in the spring application

Comment: after removing the annotation also its the same behavior

Comment: so the spring boot app have a rest controller for /practice/getprac ?

Comment: set contextPath to /prac in spring boot application

Comment: thanks it worked, i didn't got any example where its specified that context path should be match to Ingress path. Want to understand rewrite-target annotation

Comment: You have installed nginx plus ingress instead of kubernetes nginx ingress...that's why the annotation is not working

Answer (score 2):

On top the discussion, i observed one thing. We should not confuse with

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
```

And

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
```

First ensure which Ingress controller we are using and based on that decide apiVersion. I'm using "ingress-nginx" (not "nginx-ingress"). This one supports "apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1" and works charm as per "Arsene" comment.

This Ingress yaml file WORKS with "ingress-nginx" Ingress controller

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

  name: k8-exercise-03-two-app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ex03.k8.sb.two.app.ingress.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: k8-excercise-01-app-service
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /one(/|$)(.*)
          - backend:
              serviceName: k8-exercise-03-ms-service
              servicePort: 8081
            path: /two(/|$)(.*)
```

But, this Ingress yaml file NOT WORKING with "ingress-nginx" Ingress controller

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: k8-exercise-03-two-app-ingress
    annotations:
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
#       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
       ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
#  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
 #192.168.1.5 ex03.k8.sb.com is mapped in host file. 192.168.1.5 is Host machine IP
  - host: ex03.k8.sb.two.app.ingress.com
    http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
                name: k8-excercise-01-app-service
                port:
                    number: 8080  
          path: /one(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /two(/|$)(.*)
          backend:
            service:
                name: k8-exercise-03-ms-service
                port:
                    number: 8081
```

I can access the Spring Boot API Calls as like:

For App-1:

```
http://ex03.k8.sb.two.app.ingress.com/one/
Result: App One - Root

http://ex03.k8.sb.two.app.ingress.com/one/one
Result: App One - One API

http://ex03.k8.sb.two.app.ingress.com/one/api/v1/hello
Result: App One - Hello API
```

App-2:

```
http://ex03.k8.sb.two.app.ingress.com/two/message/James%20Bond
Result: App Two- Hi James Bond API
```

Finally If any one knows how to change "apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1" yaml to support "ingress-nginx" Controller, will be appreciate. Thank you. Sorry for long content

Answer (score 1):

I spend literally a day with this problem. The problem was simply the wrong nginx installed. I used helm found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) to install nginx-ingress

Install it, please use helm version 3:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

Once run, in the logs you shall see a snippet that illustrates how your ingress should look like. In case you want to do the above, you can the annotation suggested above and henceforth, you can follow tutorials [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) to achieve more such as rewrite.

My cluster is deployed on GCP using GKE

when done, this is the output log:

```
NAME: ingress-nginx
LAST DEPLOYED: Sat Apr 24 07:56:11 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
The ingress-nginx controller has been installed.
It may take a few minutes for the LoadBalancer IP to be available.
You can watch the status by running 'kubectl --namespace default get services -o wide -w ingress-nginx-controller'

An example Ingress that makes use of the controller:

  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    name: example
    namespace: foo
  spec:
    rules:
      - host: www.example.com
        http:
          paths:
            - backend:
                serviceName: exampleService
                servicePort: 80
              path: /
    # This section is only required if TLS is to be enabled for the Ingress
    tls:
        - hosts:
            - www.example.com
          secretName: example-tls

If TLS is enabled for the Ingress, a Secret containing the certificate and key must also be provided:

  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: example-tls
    namespace: foo
  data:
    tls.crt: <base64 encoded cert>
    tls.key: <base64 encoded key>
  type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

This is how it looks like now after installing it:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

  name: example
  # namespace: foo
spec:
  rules:
    - host: [your ip address].sslip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: registry-app-server
              servicePort: 8761
            path: /eureka/(.*)
          - backend:
              serviceName: api-gateway-server
              servicePort: 7000
            path: /api(/|$)(.*)
```

As you can see I am deploying spring micro-services using kubernetes(gke).
There are a lot of benefits of using nginx-ingress over built-in gke ingress, and it is more popular than [its counterparts](https://medium.com/swlh/kubernetes-ingress-controller-overview-81abbaca19ec)

Comment: "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2" resolved my issue, before configured that, I got an error: Whitelabel Error Page. I have been spent three days for this issuse. Thank you very much Arsene <3